# How should I store multiple, related models when configuration control is required?

Tags: php, node.js, database, architecture

My problem: I plan to store a "project" in a database, where a project is composed of multiple items e.g. documents, and each document has multiple items e.g. paragraphs. Paragraphs may cross-reference to paragraphs in other documents. Many teams exist, and each team may have many projects. Team members edit, update and refine the position of the cross-referenced documents until they are happy, where the document or project is then reviewed.

When a document is issued, following a review, the issued state is retained and any changes occur to a new staging/current state.

When the project is issued, it is reviewed and issued *in its entirety*. The document set, content and cross-references are then retained in that issue, so that the state is captured across the project. Any following edits are then applied to a new staging/current version, leaving the issued set available for reading as it was at the point of issue.

I have considered using a typical database setup, but am worried that a) there would quickly be a huge growth in the number of rows stored; and b) that finding the "current" set, or the set for any specific project would be too complex/fragile for reliable use.

As a variation, would storing the documents in e.g. JSON in a single document row stop the propagation of fragmented paragraphs, without incurring a large performance hit?

An alternative thought has been to assign a Git repository per-project; but then worry about storage and performance, and having to store "documents" as e.g. JSON documents or similar for the system to work efficiently. You also then end up managing staging areas per-session for each user logged in, which would be slow - right? Except GitHub, GitLab etc allow fast access to repo history...

The database (or equivalent) will be initially accessed via a web application. Eventually, it may be served to local clients over an API, or even allow local clients to work with the git repos, if that's the path that is followed. Ideally, technologies readily accessible to PHP or NodeJS would be used.

***Specific question - how would / should multiple related artefacts requiring configuration control be stored and accessed?***

Comment: This question is just entirely too broad. You are asking for architectural help which is not really the use case for SO.

Comment: Any recommendations, @nerdlyist, for narrowing it down or moving it to a more appropriate place? I appreciate your position, and felt similar when posting it, but it is a genuine technical question.

Comment: I have used https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for questions of this nature. Also, you could update the question to describe a use-case that might help. What you have described is somewhere between Git and https://quip.com/landing/document-management (I had brief exposure to it) if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: How / what is the "cross-reference"? Is it like an html link, where a part of the paragraph points towards another paragraph, or is it just a global "this paragraph in its entirety is globally referencing these other paragraph"?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier In my mind it was a whole paragraph reference, but I guess either could happen. The mechanism is flexible, as it wouldn't matter hugely.

Comment: What are these "models" that you are attempting to store? And how are they related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

The model you expose here is a very clear use case of a relational database. There is no significant performance problem in storing text in a database, and if really you manage to hit database io bottlenecks, server resources are extremely cheap these days, even though any bottlenecks would almost certainly be in your code rather than in database operations.

---

## Outline

I'll first expose thoughts about why I believe event sourcing and nosql is not a good fit, then ramble about a possible way to modelize the domain you speak of, and finish with a few example of how any action could be conducted.

### Not Event Sourcing

I first thought about event sourcing, because of its ease in managing the evolution of... events... such as editing a paragraph, reviewing an issue, etc. etc.

While trying to modelize that however, it appears that this is not practical, because to mitigate having to replay the whole event chain every time you consult an issue, you'd have to save a snapshot in a database / cache system. Supporting both the timed snapshots of the issues and event sourcing does not feel like a net win.

### Not Nosql Databases

I believe nosql databases are actually a clear loss here. Everything you speak about is totally, absolutely, relational. The structure of the domain does not seem to be ever changing, so you don't gain from a nosql flexibility.

### Yes to Relational Databases

Hence, I think that a traditional relational sql database setup should totally be preferred here.

I have first hand experience in handling relatively large amount of texts (very much like documents having multiple arbitrarily long paragraphs) and haven't have any problem with multiplicating rows. They do multiply, especially if you keep track of history, but that's what relational databases are *for*, handling numerous rows of data.

## A Tentative Model of the Database

I think most of the entities mentioned here can be modelized in a straightforward way. By straightforward, I mean having a few standard fields:

```
- id
- parent_id (when the entity is a child, such as paragraph)
- time_created: timestamp
- time_updated: timestamp 
    some dbms offer automatic updating of timestamp fields on update of the row
```

Based on that, this could be a paragraph structure. Note that the status is here, it could very well be in the `paragraph_revision` table, for instance to support reviewing further revisions of a paragraph after it was issued for a first time. Or even possibly both, as we can see a use for that later.

```
paragraph
- paragraph_id
- document_id
- created_at
- status (to_be_reviewed, in_review, reviewed, rejected, varia)
- order (maybe, if a specific order within a document is desired)
```

Careful here however, because there is a slightly tricky thing about the situation. Since we want to have a detailed history of all changes, and their authors, the actual *content* of the paragraph is in an other table, linked to the original (single) paragraph entity. Note that there is only a `created_at` timestamp value. In this paradigm, paragraph revisions are never updated, new ones are created. A database trigger or other trick can be used to enfore that.

```
paragraph_revision
- paragraph_id
- created_at
- text
- title (if needed)
- revision_number
    possibly a simple integer based revision number can be used
- author_id
```

The paragraph references can warrant another many-to-many relationship table. To get all of one paragraph references, you `select referenced_paragraph_id from paragraph_reference where paragraph_id = :id` or select all paragraph that reference a specific paragraph by switching the columns. Here, you could either reference a general paragraph, or a specific revision of a paragraph, so as not to lose history.

```
paragraph_reference
- paragraph_id
- referenced_paragraph_id
```

An issue seems to be a project, one or multiple documents, each composed of one or multiple paragraphs. Basically, an `issue` table, a `issue_document` table, linked to a single issue, and a `issue_paragraph` table, containing specific `paragraph_revision` ids, linked to these `issue_document` table. The documents table could be removed, since all paragraph are children of a document, but I prefer being able to select things directly rather then selecting them from their children.

```
issue
- issue_id
- timestamp

issue_document
- issue_id
- document_id

issue_paragraph
- document_id
- paragraph_content_id
```

### UUIDs Can Be Relevant

This could be a valid case of using uuids for entities instead of numerical ids, especially if growth makes it necessary to duplicate databases or be able to create a valid entity before sending it to the database.

### Foreign Keys Are Not Optional

While not overly complex, this is a somewhat fancy schema. Foreign keys are not an option. Every parent id must have a foreign key, the database integrity must be enforced by the database engine, or this **will** become fragile. With foreign keys, a somewhat complex system such as this can and will stay coherent over time.

## Managing Domain Actions

Hopefully the few examples I gave of how to create tables can give an idea of the general structure, now to some concrete example of how it can be practical for your different use cases.

### Creating a Project

Fairly straightforward: add a row in the `project` table, no need for any other action just yet.

### Creating a Paragraph

Two rows need to be added: one that will uniquely identify the paragraph in `paragraph`, one containing its content in `paragraph_revision`.

### Updating a Paragraph

A single row is added in the `paragraph_revision` table. If people are saving each 5 seconds, possibly a single entry can be used and updated until user makes a "I'm ok with this revision" action. (making this the only exception to the "don't update revisions" rule. Other tricks could be used, such as a `temp_paragraph_revision` table.)

### Reviewing a Paragraph

Selecting the highest numbered revision of a `paragraph_revision` would let you see the current version to be reviewed. A list of all revisions can be made by selecting all contents for a specific `paragraph_id`. Upon setting the review, the status is updated in the `paragraph` and `paragraph_revision` table, possibly preventing any revision to be made, or resetting the review status if a revision is added.

### Issuing a Paragraph or Project

Create a row in the issue table, link documents to that issue in the issue_document table, link `paragraph_revision`s to these documents in the `issue_paragraph` table. There is a choice that can be made here, that is to include the actual content of the revision in this `issue_paragraph` table, to be extra certain that a paragraph content can't be changed after an issue, but if the rule of never update a revision is used, that shouldn't be necessary.

## Conclusion

While this may seem like a lot of tables to create beforehand, most of them are rather small, and a good UML diagram would clear most hesitation on those. Joins are used in this, make sure to keep indexes on the columns that are used in these joins. All of this can be implement in most sql distributions, MariaDB if you're familiar with it and MySQL, or postgres if you know it.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about different approach - You could use [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) pattern with combination with [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (Command Query Responsibility Segregation).

Benefits:

- You can replay every change in history, see how document was generated
- You can Tag (mark) some point in the history as version - and store finalised object at that time for cache purposes (because it will not change)
- For current version - You can always keep up to date cache of concrete object so its fast to read
- If you need to return to some version of history, you just find closest marked version and then replay events from that until your point of time
- relatively easy to extends

Disadvantages:

- Different architecture style, so need different thinking
- Might take longer to implement

For storage I think SQL doesn't have to be problem, because you will be storing relatively small data (events only) and for cache, you can use NoSQL / Redis / ... whatever is Nice for you.

Scaling

- Thanks to CQRS is easy to have read only / write only nodes for database with replications
- CQRS is perfect candidate for message queue handling, means you can have fast response time and process most of the things in the background

Edited: One more thing - This is good for your main part of application, other parts (for example user management) doesn't have to follow this. Usually this solution is good only for specific purposes like this, for CRUD (or something similar) it doesn't make sense.

Edited:
How to store things

- Everything is event, so you need some storage for events (mostly will be small objects - Like ( Person X added Paragraph Y in document Z to position A) - I think no SQL database could be good solution for this or any storage supporting JSON data for example
- Then you keep Documents at your tags / current version - Means one document will consist of Many paragraphs / references / teams ... etc, all this based on recorded from history
- Means once new event is triggered this needs to happen:

  - Log new event to to storage
  - Generate new snapshot (means applying event to the last snapshot)
  - If there are references and you need them to be bi-directional - you update them as well

For storages, as main storage I will go with PostgreSQL (because I know it) and for current objects I will use redis or something similiar.

Comment: This is a totally different take on what I was asking, but I like it. I will do some research, thank you.

Comment: This is a very neat solution. To check I understand, to write: your consumers would fire events which, if authorised and accepted, lead to an entry in the events table and corresponding change to application state e.g. database models. To read: your consumers just read from the application state, but could replay/reconstruct from the events if needed? If implemented client side too, you could send events out to all consumers to keep their distributed application states up to date.

Comment: Exactly like that, what you record is actually only change. You record them in ordered manner (time, increment...) and that means you have whole history from beginning. And yes, you can just send states to other consumers to keep them up to state, because they will know how to "replay" them.

Comment: How would the baselines / issues / snapshots be stored and retrieved?

Comment: I also thought about event sourcing, but realize that it is actually *not* practical as a mean of generating issues. You do not want to have to replay the whole event chain every time you want to consult an issue. So basically, you would (as your edit shows) store issues in a database anyway. I'm not sure of the gain of having to support both modes (simple satabase storage for issues + event sourcing for project / document management)

Comment: @M.Kebza this answer was really useful, thank you very much for your time. I'm afraid I awarded the bounty to another answer, as it covered all of the issues in the question, and could be immediately applied to solve the problem. Your answer was in top position until just a few hours ago! I will absolutely look into  this further, and have learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if storing huge amount of JSONs or documents in DB is right approach. I see considerable amount of time in fetching the JSONs from DB. The other point with storing huge amount of data in DB is with migration. In the event of migration or backup, the amount of resource utilization and time it takes to migrate may become a challenge.

How about using some of the Content Management Systems which comes with lot of features like version control, archive, storage optimization and availability. We used Documentum in previous projects and it was serving all our needs. Have the documents stored in content management systems and link them with your project (DB) to maintain hierarchical, approval process flows.

This is more of a comment and not the answer that you are looking for but unfortunately we have character limitation for comments :)